# Consider the following expression about natural number: $\forall n\exists m: m^{2}=n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

I understood the first part and made an attempt.
Then the question asked me to demonstrate an expression about natural numbers of my own which has an opposite truth value to the one above and explain it. Am I heading in the right direction?

$(\forall n\exists m\in\mathbb{N}:
  m^{2}=n$ 
 The above claim states that for all n
 , there exists some m
  such that $m^{2}=n$
 . Lets test the claim. $0^{2} = 0$,
$1^{2} = 1$,
$(2^{2}=4) \neq 2$.
 This expression is false since $m=(2)^{2}=4$ is not equal to $n=2$
 .An expression which has an opposite truth value to the above expression is $\forall m\exists m\in\mathbb{N}:
  \surd(m^{2})=n$
 . It claims that for all n there exists some m element of natural numbers, such that $\surd(m^{2})=n$
 . This will be true for all values since the square is cancelled out by the square root so m is always equal to n
 .

Comment: You need to surround formulas with dollar signs.

Comment: The usual formal language that you use to describe the natural numbers does not include the symbol  $ \sqrt $.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it @user3491648

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you give for why the given statement is false is incorrect. You say yourself that the statement claims that for any natural number $n$ there exists some natural number $m$ such that $m^2=n$. So, let's (indeed) check for a few values: if $n=0$, then can you find some $m$ such that $m^2=n$? Well, that means to solve $m^2=0$, and of course the natural number $m=0$ solves this. When $n=1$ can you find some $m$ such that $m^2=n$? Well, that means solving $m^2=1$, and of course the natural number $m=1$ solves this. When $n=2$ can you find some $m$ such that $m^2=n$? Well, maybe you know something about the solution for this case and can conclude something about your homework question.

As for finding your own expression with the opposite truth value, it's really much easier than you think.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did take help to get the solution but I attempted the question only after I thought i'd understood the question. I don't think i really understood it then.
and thanks professor :)